# Edit text on top of an image and save in android?

Tags: android, image, textview, android-canvas

I notice that a Canvas and a paint are the standard ways to add text to an image e.g:

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.Black);
myPaint.setTextSize(25);
myCanvas.drawText("Test test test", 0, 0, myPaint); //Set the position
```

, but instead of having a separate textview above the image that when updated redraws the canvas with the updated text - what if I want to edit the text *on top of the image* so that as I type via the android keyb the text renders exactly as it will on the final edited bitmap - what kind of approach can I take for that?

I guess imagine a meme generator that lets you type the impact font directly onto the image, thats the kind of ui I want to achieve. e.g. like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WJew.jpg - so display the sun graphic, but the text on top is editable by clicking and the newly created text will save with the image exactly as it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach you might consider is to use EditText positioned in the right places over your image.  Use a transparent background to give the impression that the text is part of the image.

When you want save the image, you can use drawText() to compose the final result and save that.  It will take some work to get the Paint you use to draw the text right, in particular make sure you dither and use anti-aliasing.  Or you could getDrawingCache() to get a bitmap representation of the EditText and draw that on top of your background image.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good idea for a browser application, which the user interacts with a mouse and a keyboard. It'd feel like an image editor (either raster like Photoshop or vector like Inkscape).

The problem with an Android device is that likely the user only has the touchscreen to input characters, which means that most of the screen space is taken by the virtual keyboard. This is true even for bigger screens, like tablets' ones.

Technically speaking, you don't need to subclass `View`: using appropriate background and font, you should be ok with a simple `EditText`. The problem is that this *live preview* feature is mostly useless on a touchscreen device, so my strong advise is doing like a webapp and generate the image in the back office.